# Azure Data explorer deletion recovery

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I just accidently deleted an azure data explorer cluster.

Is it possible to restore it? If so, how can I restore it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, deletion of a cluster isn't a recoverable operation. That said, you can open a support request (via the Azure portal) and see if it's possible in your specific case.